# Add og: image to specific pages in Hugo

Tags: image, seo, meta, hugo

I was just handed a hugo site. And I need to add an og:image for let's say example `www.site.com/page1` as well as subpages `www.site.com/page1/something` and a few dozen items more...

I am reading the docs and found this.

```
// First in config.toml use the following:
baseURL = "//example.com" [params] og_image = "/some-image.jpg"

// Then in a post’s frontmater set a parameter for the OpenGraph image
og_image = "/images/1.jpg"

// And in the HEAD partial put the following:
> {{ if .Params.og_image }} > `` > `` > {{ else }} > `` > `` > {{ end }}
// And that’s it.
```

I am having trouble understanding what to put in `params`. What does it mean with ``` > `` > ``` Where should I include the `meta-tag`, could you please explain this to me? I have never used Hugo before, and the docs are a little bit weird... Basically, for every page and subpage like that, I want to use an image for og:image..

Currently in my `config.yaml`, I have :

```
baseurl: "www.site.com/"
```

Ans in the Header
{{ .Hugo.Generator }}

```
    {{ if isset $.Params "ogtype" }}
    <meta property="og:type" content="{{ .Params.ogtype }}">
    {{ end }}

    {{ if isset $.Params "ogimage" }}
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@siteLtD">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{ .Params.title }}">
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="{{ .Params.title }}">
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ .Params.ogimage }}">
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="{{ .Params.ogimage }}">
    {{ else }}
    <meta property="og:image" content="www.site.com/images/site-ogi.png">
```

If you could guide me on what do I need to actually include to make the subpages get a specific image, it would be great thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your image in the `config.yaml`. Then I am assuming your theme's 'post's' front matter takes in an og param too. The head partial fetches these params once set. Then depending your template and config, something like:

```
{{ with .Params.images }}{{ range something . }}
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ . | absURL }}" />
{{ end }}
```

See: https://gohugo.io/templates/internal/#configure-open-graph
& https://gohugo.io/variables/page/

Also, since you are really new to Hugo, I would recommend to read up the docs on templates, using partials, etc. to better understand where to use `meta-tag` and other best practices since this can also vary from theme to theme. This should also help: http://brendan-quinn.xyz/post/working-with-hugos-internal-partial-templates-facebook-and-open-graph/